# Change the tense of a text

Tags: text-processing

I am looking for a program that can:

- Change the tense of a text, e.g. from present to past tense, in which case "I do X and make Y" would be transformed into "I did X and made Y".

If possible:

- Windows 7
- free
- can be used with LaTeX